# List modified policy options

Tags: windows-8, group-policy

In Windows 8, how can I find out what local policies I have modified from their default No Set values?

Basically, I've tinkered with my Windows 8 laptop until i finally like it after 3 or 4 months of use.  A lot of this was because I've edited the local policies.

But, I have no idea of the entire list of changes I've made.

Alternatively, is there a way to export the local policy and possibly reapply it to another Windows 8 machine?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want secedit. Start a command prompt as administrator (right click -> Run as admin).

```
secedit /export /cfg "filename"
```

Then `secedit /import /cfg "filename"` on the other machine.

It's plain text, but not the most user friendly. You can also export/import to security template databases. You'll definitely want to review all the options so you get exactly what you want.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875548.aspx

Comment: I'll give it a shot and will report back.  I saw the secedit and was wondering if it would do everything, not just security policies.

Comment: Unless I've lost my marbles (a possibility) local "group policy" is referred to as security policy. Group policy comes from domain membership and such.

Comment: I'm not in front of my Win8 machine, but this showed up for Win7, which is very similar in many ways: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itproxpsp/thread/2030e62e-a60d-442a-8455-647b569caffb

Comment: Coming back here after a year or so to say this worked.  :)